# How to submit a custom jar to yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm learning yarn.I try to submit a custom jar file to yarn, it works well, but I have not found the job on yarn web ui.

[image]

how does it works?

Comment: What does your JAR code actually do that it needs to use YARN?

Comment: A simple hello-world program. I got answer from web site.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html

Comment: That page is for building a yarn application, though, not just running a simple jar program. If you want to run a random app, I'd suggest looking at Apache Oozie, as it's more of a "action scheduler", like can be done in Kubernetes, but you could also just run `java jar` over ssh (or not). You don't need YARN to run the code